# Socket.io (Node.js) Doesn't Detect Connected QTcpSocket

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, qt, qtcpsocket

I'm trying to connect a QTcpSocket to a Nodejs application.
The C++ QT Code is:

```
nodeSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
nodeSocket->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 3000);
if (nodeSocket->waitForConnected(3000))
{
    qDebug() << "Connected!";
}
```

The Node.js code is:

```
var server = express().listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
          console.log('A new client connected! ID: ' + socket.id);
          });
```

I know the QT socket is able to connect and it goes through the condition for connecting, but it's not getting through io.sockets.on in the Javascript function to indicate that a new client is connected.

Answer (score 3):

`socket.io` is not for regular TCP sockets. What you want instead is the built-in [`net`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html) module, specifically [`net.createServer()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) which returns a [`net.Server`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_class_net_server) instance that you can use to listen for plain TCP connections.

Comment: I would rather not change the Node code. I tried using just QWebSocket (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwebsockets-echoclient-echoclient-cpp.html), but it wouldn't connect at all.

Comment: `socket.io` is typically for browsers connecting to the server. You could use websockets, but then you have to have an implementation of the socket.io protocol to use in conjunction with the websocket.